# pandas: check existence value in column

Tags: pandas

I want to check if the value unknown exist in the column place group by date.
If the value does not exist then i want to add row with value unknown, and 0 in the sum.

How should i do it please?

```
date        place     sum_
2021-07-04   NY       200
2021-07-04   LA       100
2021-07-04   MILAN    300
2021-07-04   PARIS    100
2021-07-05   NY       200
2021-07-05   LA       100
2021-07-05   MILAN    200
2021-07-05   PARIS    50
2021-07-05   unknown  100
```

**expected output**

```
date        place     sum_
2021-07-04   NY       100
2021-07-04   LA       200
2021-07-04   MILAN    300
2021-07-04   PARIS    100
2021-07-04   unknown   0
2021-07-05   NY       200
2021-07-05   LA       100
2021-07-05   MILAN    100
2021-07-05   PARIS    50
2021-07-05   unknown  200
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check for `unknown` by date, you can use list comprehension and concat the results:

```
s = [(x, "unknown", 0) for x, y in df.groupby("date")["place"] if not y.eq("unknown").any()]

print (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(s, columns=df.columns)], ignore_index=True))

         date    place  sum_
0  2021-07-04       NY   200
1  2021-07-04       LA   100
2  2021-07-04    MILAN   300
3  2021-07-04    PARIS   100
4  2021-07-05       NY   200
5  2021-07-05       LA   100
6  2021-07-05    MILAN   200
7  2021-07-05    PARIS    50
8  2021-07-05  unknown   100
9  2021-07-04  unknown     0
```

A general solution which might or might not be what you want is to create cartesian product of `date` and `place` using `pd.MultiIndex`, then `reindex`:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["date"].unique(), df["place"].unique()],
                                 names=["date", "place"])

print (df.set_index(["date", "place"]).reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index())

         date    place  sum_
0  2021-07-04       NY   200
1  2021-07-04       LA   100
2  2021-07-04    MILAN   300
3  2021-07-04    PARIS   100
4  2021-07-04  unknown     0
5  2021-07-05       NY   200
6  2021-07-05       LA   100
7  2021-07-05    MILAN   200
8  2021-07-05    PARIS    50
9  2021-07-05  unknown   100
```